# How to require jQuery plugin in jest test file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jestjs

I have developed a simple jQuery plugin and I want to perform some automated testing using facebook's [jestjs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) framework.

The plugin is a self executed function:

**Plugin code**

```
; (function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    var pluginName = 'searchAreaControl';

    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.el = element;
        this.$el = $(element);   
        this.opt = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn[pluginName].defaults, options);
        this.rootClassName = 'elem-searchAreaControl';
        this.popupID = null;
        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {
      ...
    }

    // Methods ...

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

The project's folder structure is like this:

```
Root
 |
 +-- __test__
 |   |
 |   +-- sum.test.js
 |
 +-- searchAreaControl
 |   |
 |   +-- css
 |   +-- searchAreaControl.js
 |
 +-- node_modules
 |
// And other folders
```

**sum.test.js** (Jest test)

```
jest.dontMock('jquery').dontMock('searchAreaControl');
var $ = require('jquery');
var searchAreaControl = require('../searchAreaControl/searchAreaControl');

test('Initialize plugin', function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = '<button id="myButton" class="elem-searchAreaControl" type="button"></button>';
    $('#myButton').searchAreaControl();
    expect($('#myButton').hasClass('elem-searchAreaControl')).toEqual(true);
});
```

In the test file, I create a button element and try to initialize the `searchAreaControl` plugin on it. I expect that, after the initialization, this button element will have the class `elem-searchAreaControl`.

I run

```
npm test
```

And I get this error:

> Cannot find module 'searchAreaControl' from 'sum.test.js'

As soon as `searchAreaControl.js` is not a module I suppose I cannot use `require('searchAreaControl')`. Does anyone have the experience to indicate a solution?

Here is the full code [Github repo](https://github.com/kapantzak/SearchAreaControl/tree/develop).

Answer (score 8):

package.json configuration:

```js
"jest": {
        "setupFiles": ["./source/setup-jest.js"]
 },
```

source/setup-jest.js configuration:

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
global.$ = $;
global.jQuery = $;
```

Answer (score 6):

I create setup-jest.js

```
global.window = window
global.$ = require('jquery');
```

in package.json

```
"jest": {
   "setupFiles": ["./setup-jest.js"]
}
```

and then it's automatic require jQuery when start `npm test`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jest 27+, node is now the default `testEnvironment`. If you need to use jQuery in jest setup script, make sure to first change the `testEnvironment` back to `jsdom`.

in `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom'
}
```

in `jest.setup.js`:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
global.$ = $;

// If you want to mock bootstrap
global.$.fn.modal = jest.fn(() => $());
global.$.fn.carousel = jest.fn(() => $());
global.$.fn.tooltip = jest.fn(() => $());
```

If you are using TypeScript, in a global typings file (e.g. `global.d.ts` at the root of your project), add:

```
interface Window {
  $: typeof import('jquery');
}
```

Comment: when I do that, i get an error: Property '$' does not exist on type 'Global & typeof globalThis'. Do you know why?

Comment: I have edited the answer. If you are using TypeScript, you need to declare `$` as a member of `Window`.